# Do translators often convert units of measurement when translating into Japanese?

Tags: translation

Converting units into metric ones is quite a common translation practice in my country (especially when translating from languages of some backward countries). I wonder whether translators often do so translating into Japanese, or they just leave the original units and add footnotes to explain in metric terms.

Comment: @jack Please don't answer questions in comments.

Answer (score 7):

There is no hard rule about this, and each translator decides whether they will convert units or not, taking many things into consideration.

- Young readers may not understand foreign units at all.
- The importance of each figure depends on the context. Most Japanese people cannot instantly tell if a 身長6.5フィートの男 is tall or not, but 身長2メートルの男 is instantly understandable as a tall man. If you need to convey the clear image of his height in the story, it's probably better to convert. But converting the length of *Titanic* (882 ft) may not be that important; usually all you need to understand is "it was a large ship" :)
- Nevertheless, unconverted and unfamiliar units can add a good, exotic atmosphere to the scene. Understandably, some people always dislike unit conversions. Probably no one wants to see [500 Miles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ExNM0RrH0o) translated as 800キロメートル.

For example, if I remember correctly, one dubbed version of *Back To The Future* uses 時速88マイル to describe the speed to achieve temporal displacement. Another version uses  時速142キロ, which is far familiar to the Japanese audience.

Comment: Just imagining [this song translated...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbNlMtqrYS0) ８００キロも歩くだろう更に８００キロも歩くだろう